# Como alterar o nome da coluna References pelo Fluent Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Na classe "LOG", estou tentando indicar o nome da coluna, o qual é um FK, usando References do FluentNHibernate. Tenho o seguinte estrutura de classe:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class PessoaAcesso : Pessoa
{
    public virtual string Login { get; set; }

    public virtual string Senha { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Administrador { get; set; }

    public virtual bool AcessoLiberado { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Log> Logs { get; set; }

    public PessoaAcesso()
    {
        Logs = new List<Log>();
    }
}

public class Log
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual PessoaAcesso PessoaAcesso { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime DataHora { get; set; }

    public virtual LogAcao Acao { get; set; }

    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

E seus mapenamentos:

```
public class PessoaMap : ClassMap<Pessoa>
{
    public PessoaMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.Nome)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(100);
    }
}

public class PessoaAcessoMap : SubclassMap<PessoaAcesso>
{
    public PessoaAcessoMap()
    {
        KeyColumn("Id_Pessoa");

        Map(x => x.Login)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(50);

        Map(x => x.Senha)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(100);

        Map(x => x.Administrador)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.AcessoLiberado)
            .Not.Nullable();

        HasMany(x => x.Logs)
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class LogMap : ClassMap<Log>
{
    public LogMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.DataHora)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Acao)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .CustomType<int>();

        Map(x => x.Descricao)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(200);

        References(x => x.PessoaAcesso)
            .Column("Id_PessoaAcesso")
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Ao gerar a tabela no SQL Server, ele cria a coluna "Id_PessoaAcesso" corretamente, porém TAMBÉM cria a coluna "PessoaAcesso_id" permitindo null.

Já tentei indicar o nome da coluna dessa forma, mas obtém o mesmo resultado inesperado:

```
References(x => x.PessoaAcesso, "Id_PessoaAcesso")
```

Não estou entendendo o porque de estar criando uma coluna a mais. O que pode ser?

Comment: Pode postar o mapeamento da class de PessoaAcesso?

Comment: Adicionado @Fernando

Comment: `SubclassMap` faz o que, altera algum comportamento do mapeamento? Pode postar seu código também?

Comment: Adicionei a estrutura completa @Fernando

Comment: `SubclassMap` é igual `PessoaMap`? Que método é `KeyColumn("Id_Pessoa");`?

Comment: Estou usando SubClassMap, pois PessoaAcesso faz relação 1:1 com Pessoa (herança). Quanto isso está funcionando corretamente. O Problema está com o Log.

Comment: @Fernando adicionei no PessoaAcessoMap - HasMany(x => x.Logs).KeyColumn("Id_PessoaAcesso") e no LogMap - References(x => x.PessoaAcesso).Column("Id_PessoaAcesso"), e agora funcionou como esperado. Só não entendi direito o porque preciso indicar em ambas as relações o nome do Id. Crio uma resposta com essa solução, ou edito a pergunta?

Comment: Se seu problema foi resolvido, crie uma resposta com sua solução para que outros, possam identificar facilmente a solução para o problema. E também fica mais claro a solução para podermos analisar a sua duvida.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz a indicação do nome da coluna tanto para PessoaMap() quanto para LogMap(). Funcionou.

```
public class PessoaAcessoMap : SubclassMap<PessoaAcesso>
{
    public PessoaAcessoMap()
    {
        KeyColumn("Id_Pessoa");

        Map(x => x.Login)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(50);

        Map(x => x.Senha)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(100);

        Map(x => x.Administrador)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.AcessoLiberado)
            .Not.Nullable();

        HasMany(x => x.Logs)
            .KeyColumn("Id_PessoaAcesso")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class LogMap : ClassMap<Log>
{
    public LogMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.DataHora)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Acao)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .CustomType<int>();

        Map(x => x.Descricao)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(200);

        References(x => x.PessoaAcesso)
            .Column("Id_PessoaAcesso")
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Comment: A sim agora entendi, no Logs, você não estava especificando o nome da coluna para a relação HasMany, então estava utilizando a nomenclatura padrão, no caso: nome da classe + "_Id" (PessoaAcesso_Id), e já na relação References, você estava especificando um nome para a coluna, então ele estava atendendo os 2 mapeamentos.